# How to convert the value returns by the ?format=json of certain address into real BTC format like i.e 0.00232

Tags: json, format, bitcoin, blockchain

Need help to convert the value parameter from this page `https://blockchain.info/address/1CVrg5P8s3g7byiqr9bBpjjxZV7Gp3fzRG/?format=json&filter=2` transaction to a real BTC number like `0.00232`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By dividing with `10^8`:

```
  {
     "spent":true,
     "tx_index":173071723,
     "type":0,
     "addr":"16jXf2iHuvtPY6D9NumQBKff5mLUKCP6nA",
     "value":18003000,
     "n":1,
     "script":"76a9143ee3b07bbcd8d9748b4f3b906fc8c5adeca0a88188ac"
  }
```

Where `value` is `18003000 / 10^8 = 0.18003` BTC.

Why `10^8`? That's the smallest denomination of 1 BTC which is called [Satoshi](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/114/6441). 100000000 Satoshi = 1 BTC.